# Print a specific value from array in ci

Tags: php

I stored some data to an array using this code (`$rval['arr']`):

```
$id = $this->input->get("id");
$rval['arr'] = $this->General_model->details($id);
```

When I print my result by using `print_r($rval['arr']);` it shows like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 54 [name] => Rajib [address] => DumDum [mobile] => 9865321245 [doj] => 21-2-2010 [fare] => 1245 [img_name] => Penguins.jpg ) )
```

Now I want to store the address value to a variable like `add`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$address=$rval['arr'][0]['address'];
```

[demo](http://phpio.net/s/4s7)

Comment: Because of your array key is `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in a `foreach()` loop:

```
foreach($rval['arr'] as $array){
  echo $array['name'];
  echo $array['address'];
  echo $array['mobile'];
}
```